# Design language system

Tags: design, language, system

I hope this is relevant to UX as most articles about DLS`s are written by UX designers.

I read many articles about it but couldn`t find any mentions about:

1. Who is responsible with creating a DLS ( an UX designer , a team composed of who ? )
2. What software is best to be used to mantain a DLS ?

I would appreciate any personal experiences that you had with a design language system, as I am asked to create one all by myself and find it way to complex to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I might be mistaken but DLS is just a new name for the very old practice of [standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardization). In a development environment this would either be made by one or more [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps), the IT department, or however proposes a new reform. I highly recommend that at least one person on your DSL team knows how to script. A 3 minute script of 20 lines of code can save you dozens of hours. Also, if possible, ask the opinion of a **good** software architect or language designer since the exercise is not all that different.

Comment: @armatita close buy not quite. Language allows for bending and breaking of rules. Standardization is more strict and, in the traditional sense, more technical. For example "bolts with 1mm thread" must be followed or your machine cannot be assembled, but "images use greyscale with red color pops" can be bent to include orange or skintone hues if that suits the situation better.

Comment: @PixelSnader That is still a standardization. The standard just happens to be upper in the chain of decisions. Even for the bolt example, you might have a standard for the length but not for the quantity of nickel in its composition (leaving that decision for "whatever suits the situation better). Again I might be mistaken, but I don't see any significant difference of approach between applying a company standard for UX or development, for example. And I've done both.

Comment: You are both right :)) @PixelSnader - It depends on the company. Some companies do not allow deviations from their "Design system" and might even punish it. Others accept proposals of improvements inside the system discuss them and update the system if it is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A design system, pattern library, brand standard, etc (all names for similar things) **should be created by whoever cares enough to make it happen** AND has the blessing of the organization/culture to make decisions about a standard. It could be one person in a small org or a team with representation from many Product Lines. It all depends on the org. Regardless, the people responsible for creating a tool like this should be senior enough to understand the unique complexities of the organization AND able to identify opportunities for element reuse.
2. **Tools will depend greatly on WHAT** is in the system. Are you reusing code components? Pattern examples and use cases? Visual button styles? You could use anything from Dropbox to a Git Repo to a blog platform to a visual library tool like Craft from Invision. The only real thing that matters is that everyone who needs to learn from or apply the library has easy access. If it's not easy, nobody will use it.
3. **From a creation standpoint** process is more important than tools. When you start you should know how this will grow. Who can suggest changes? Who approves changes? Is there a log of the problem being solved and how it changes? How do you verify that your system is being implemented correctly? You should resolve all that stuff BEFORE worrying about how you'll actually build a Design System.

Comment: Awesome. Will return with a reply but thanks !